# Starting with CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: ios, xcode, tcp, cocoaasyncsocket

I've been looking for ways to send files (small sound recorded on the iphone) over TCP to a server and from the server to other devices.
It seems like the easiest way to do so would be using the CocoaAsyncSocket project.
(Is it true?)

However, while I could find many examples on how to use it, I couldn't find a single explanation on how to install it.

I'm relatively new to iOS and Xcode and quite lost in that.
Could someone please explain to me how to get the library? (I know how to add a library to my project, however I only found download for the .m files thru the gitHub)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library comes with a header file (either AsyncSocket.h or GCDAsyncSocket.h) and an implement file (either AsyncSocket.m or GCDAsyncSocket.m).  All you need is to copy the .h and .m in your project.  And using the #import statement to include the AsyncSocket or GCDAsyncSocket class in your class to use it.  The library as you downloaded is not in a static library or framework compiled format.  If you go thru the examples from the same author, you will see how it was done.

Comment: I c, thank you!
Is it a good platform for sending small files?

Comment: I have used it for files in 1k to 90MB.

Comment: That's great!
Do you have a guide on how to send files with it? since i'm not on a mac right now, i don't have the option of playing with it and wanted to learn on it a bti

Comment: Thanks alot! this is exactly what i've been looking for!